# Dot product with a unit vector in the direction of $b$: what does it represent?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, inner-products

Let $F:\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}^3$ be of class $C^2$ and let $a, b\in\mathbb{R}^3$ be two nonnull vectors. Let $F(x) = F(x_1, x_2, x_3)$.

Consider the vector given by
$$\left(\sum_{i=1}^3 \frac{\partial F_1}{\partial x_i} a_i, \sum_{i=1}^3 \frac{\partial F_2}{\partial x_i} a_i, \sum_{i=1}^3 \frac{\partial F_3}{\partial x_i} a_i \right).$$

Denoting by $\widehat{b}$ the unit vector in the direction of the vector $b$, I am trying to understand what
$$\left(\sum_{i=1}^3 \frac{\partial F_1}{\partial x_i} a_i, \sum_{i=1}^3 \frac{\partial F_2}{\partial x_i} a_i, \sum_{i=1}^3 \frac{\partial F_3}{\partial x_i} a_i \right)\cdot\widehat{b}$$
does represent.

If, e.g. $b$ is a vector in the direction of the $y$-axis, I would say that
$$\left(\sum_{i=1}^3 \frac{\partial F_1}{\partial x_i} a_i, \sum_{i=1}^3 \frac{\partial F_2}{\partial x_i} a_i, \sum_{i=1}^3 \frac{\partial F_3}{\partial x_i} a_i \right)\cdot\widehat{b} = \sum_{i=1}^3 \frac{\partial F_2}{\partial x_i} a_i,$$
but I am not sure what does that scalar product represent in general (I mean, $b$ could be in an "easy" direction, but also in the $x+y$ direction and others more complicated).

Could someone please help me in understanding that? Is that related with directional derivative?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can take $\hat b$ inside the derivative:

$$
\left(\sum_{i=1}^3 \frac{\partial F_1}{\partial x_i} a_i, \sum_{i=1}^3 \frac{\partial F_2}{\partial x_i} a_i, \sum_{i=1}^3 \frac{\partial F_3}{\partial x_i} a_i \right)\cdot\widehat{b}=\sum_{i=1}^3\frac{\partial(F\cdot\hat b)}{\partial x_i}a_i\;.
$$

So this is the directional derivative along $a$ of the scalar function $F\cdot\hat b$, the component of $F$ along $\hat b$.